# .net core entity framework Where clause on Child object

Tags: .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Hi here my Object Definition

```
List<SeasonBasket> baskets = base.Factory.Context.SeasonBasket
.Include (s=> s.Season)
    .ThenInclude (dt => dt.DivisionTeam)
.Include(sbl => sbl.SeasonBasketLocalisation)
.Include(sbm => sbm.SeasonBasketMatch)
    .ThenInclude(m => m.Match)
        .ThenInclude(p => p.Period)
.ThenInclude(pt => pt.PeriodType)
    .ThenInclude(ptl => ptl.PeriodTypeLocalisation)
.Include(sbm => sbm.SeasonBasketMatch)
    .ThenInclude(m => m.Match)
        .ThenInclude(p => p.Period)
            .ThenInclude(c => c.Challenge)
                .ThenInclude(cl => cl.ChallengeLocalisation)
.Include(sbm => sbm.SeasonBasketMatch)
    .ThenInclude(sf => sf.SeasonFight)
        .ThenInclude(tf => tf.TeamFight)
            .ThenInclude(t => t.Team)        
                .ThenInclude(dt => dt.DivisionTeam)        
.Include(sbm => sbm.SeasonBasketMatch)
    .ThenInclude(sf => sf.SeasonFight)
        .ThenInclude(sfpr => sfpr.SeasonFightPeriodResult)   
.Where(x =>
       x.Season.DivisionTeam.Where(y=> y.TeamId.Equals(TeamId) && y.SeasonId.Equals(seasonId)).Count() > 0
       &&
       x.SeasonId.Equals(seasonId)
       )

.ToList();
```

My problem is that it load all parent object event if the child object does not contains the specified teamId.

My question is how can i achieve this in 1 query

Comment: Off-topic: do yourself a favor and use plural names for collections. On-topic: first try the query without all these includes. Does it still not return the correct results? Also, use `==` instead of `Equals`, and `Any` instead of `Count() > 0` (performs better).

Comment: I think that because you are using the equals function you may be evaluating that where clause in memory instead of in SQL causing everything to be loaded

Comment: I know you're trying to do one query, however it may be simpler to breaking the query up and EF to populate the navigation properties?  Look at the example here (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/read-related-data).  second one under eager loading.

Comment: Seems i won't have a choice to do this using a Real Sql query, as it's not filtering on the TeamFight.TeamId any way i try this. and breaking up the query into subquery is not an option

Comment: So you are trying to filter the Season by the division team? Are these single objects or collections?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

Now this should give you all of the data that you are trying to get, but it won't give you a list of SeasonBasket and FYI this is going to be a SERIOUSLY expensive query.

```
List<DivisionTeam> divisionTeams = base.Factory.Context.DivisionTeam
       .Include(dt => dt.Season)
           .ThenInclude(s => s.SeasonBasket)
           .ThenInclude(sb => sb.SeasonBasketMatch)
           .ThenInclude(sbm => sbm.Match)
           .ThenInclude(m => m.Period)
           .ThenInclude(pt => pt.PeriodType)
           .ThenInclude(ptl => ptl.PeriodTypeLocalisation)
       .Include(dt => dt.Season)
           .ThenInclude(s => s.SeasonBasket)
           .ThenInclude(sb => sb.SeasonBasketMatch)
           .ThenInclude(m => m.Match)
           .ThenInclude(p => p.Period)
           .ThenInclude(c => c.Challenge)
           .ThenInclude(cl => cl.ChallengeLocalisation)
       .Include(dt => dt.Season)
           .ThenInclude(s => s.SeasonBasket)
           .ThenInclude(sb => sb.SeasonBasketMatch)
           .ThenInclude(sf => sf.SeasonFight)
           .ThenInclude(tf => tf.TeamFight)
           .ThenInclude(t => t.Team)        
           .ThenInclude(dt => dt.DivisionTeam) 
       .Include(dt => dt.Season)
           .ThenInclude(s => s.SeasonBasket)
           .ThenInclude(sb => sb.SeasonBasketMatch)
           .ThenInclude(sf => sf.SeasonFight)
           .ThenInclude(sfpr => sfpr.SeasonFightPeriodResult)
       .Include(dt => dt.Season)
           .ThenInclude(s => s.SeasonBasket)
           .ThenInclude(sb => sb.SeasonBasketMatch)
           .ThenInclude(sbl => sbl.SeasonBasketLocalisation)
       .Where(y => y.TeamId == TeamId && y.SeasonId == seasonId)
       .ToList();
```